# "Add printer" does not work for canon mp560 in 20.04

Tags: printing, 20.04, canon, cups-lpd

On 18.04 MP560 is listed in *available printers* but not in 20.04.

What alternatives are there?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. What I did was add my user to the `lpadmin` group. Type:

```bash
sudo usermod -a -G lpadmin username
```

(Replace *`username`* with your actual username.)

Once I did that, I was able to add the printer.

Comment: Thank you that worked a treat